# Is it possible to assign a proxy for each thread in Jakarta Common's HTTPClient?

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy, apache-commons-httpclient

I want to have multiple threads, each using a different proxy for Jakarta Common's HTTPClient. Last time I check, it was only possible to set one global/static proxy for this API. Does anyone how to accomplish the prior stated goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the proxy is set on each httpclient instance.  Therefore, it should be possible to define one httpclient instance per thread, each having their own proxy settings.

Comment: I think you are right. I haven't used common-httpclient in awhile (>2 years) and back then it may have been using URLConnection instead of SocketConnection, thus making the only way to set a proxy was through an environment variable.